# Printing the Cracker Barrel Game

Tags: code-golf, board-game

**Revised formatting and instructions**

Given a list of moves for a [Cracker Barrel peg board game](http://www.memory-improvement-tips.com/pegs.html), or as @Steveverrill stated, Peg Triangle Solitaire:

```
Game 1        Game 2         Game 3
1:  0 ,-1, -1   C, -1, -1     4, -1, -1  #starting point
2:  3, 1, 0     3, 7, C       B, 7, 4    #jump_from, jump_over, jump_to
3:  A, 6, 3     0, 1, 3       D, C, B
4:  8, 4, 1     6, 3, 1       5, 8, C
5:  B, 7, 4     5, 2, 0       1, 4, 8
6:  2, 4, 7     C, 8, 5       E, 9, 5
7:  D, C, B     A, B, C       6, 3, 1
8:  9, 5, 2     D, C, B       2, 5, 9
9:  1, 3, 6     9, 5, 2       B, C, D
10: 0, 2, 5     1, 4, 8       9, 8, 7
11: 6, 7, 8     0, 2, 5       0, 1, 3
12: 5, 8, C     5, 8, C       3, 7, C
13: B, C, D     B, C, D       D, C, B
14: E, D, C     E, D, C       A, B, C
```

**Here is your task**

- Write a program that takes a list of moves, each move has three arguments which are slots on the board (jump_from, jump_over, jump_to). Move the peg from jump_from to jump_to and remove jump_over. (If that is unclear then read the instructions linked at the top)
- Print the board for each move

  - The direction of the move a.k.a. the arrow
  - The slot jumped from a.k.a. the `*`
  - The slot jumped to (if peg 3 was in slot 3, and jumped to slot 0, then print a 3 in slot 0)
  - print a `.` for any empty slots

**How to play**

-If you don't understand these rules then there is a link at the top.

I've provided three different games that result in one peg remaining. The idea of the game is to start with one peg missing in the board and remove pegs until there is one left. A move is jumping over a peg into an empty slot and removing the peg you jumped over. Valid moves are diagonals and horizontal moves only. Example (assume slots 1, 2, 3, and 6 are open):

> 8 over 4 to 1 is valid
>
> 8 over 7 to 6 is valid
>
> 8 over 7 or 4 to 3 is invalid
>
> B over 7 and 4 is invalid

Your output should look like the following. Each board printed is one move

(Use hex instead of decimal since printing the board in decimal causes the last row to be too wide)

```
This is Game 1 from the move set at the top

       / 0 \        #This is the board with all slots filled
      / 1 2 \       
     / 3 4 5 \      
    / 6 7 8 9 \     
   / A B C D E \ 

       / * \        #Move 1: remove the first peg which is 0
      / 1 2 \       
     / 3 4 5 \      
    / 6 7 8 9 \     
   / A B C D E \    

       / 3 \        #Move 2: Move peg 3 from slot 3 over slot 1 to slot 0
      / ↗ 2 \       Remove peg 1 from slot 1
     / * 4 5 \      
    / 6 7 8 9 \     
   / A B C D E \    

       / 3 \        #Move 3
      / . 2 \       
     / A 4 5 \      
    / ↗ 7 8 9 \     
   / * B C D E \    

       / 3 \        #Move 4
      / 8 2 \       
     / A ↖ 5 \      
    / . 7 * 9 \     
   / . B C D E \    

       / 3 \        #Move 5
      / 8 2 \       
     / A B 5 \      
    / . ↗ . 9 \     
   / . * C D E \    

       / 3 \        #Move 6
      / 8 * \       
     / A ↙ 5 \      
    / . 2 . 9 \     
   / . . C D E \    

       / 3 \       #Move 7
      / 8 . \       
     / A . 5 \      
    / . 2 . 9 \     
   / . D ← * E \    

       / 3 \        #Move 8
      / 8 9 \       
     / A . ↖ \      
    / . 2 . * \     
   / . D . . E \    

       / 3 \        #Move 9:
      / * 9 \       Move peg 8 from slot 1 over slot 3 to slot 6
     / ↙ . . \      Remove peg A
    / 8 2 . . \     
   / . D . . E \    

       / * \        #Move 10
      / . ↘ \       
     / . . 3 \      
    / 8 2 . . \     
   / . D . . E \    

       / . \        #Move 11
      / . . \       
     / . . 3 \      
    / * → 8 . \     
   / . D . . E \    

       / . \        #Move 12
      / . . \       
     / . . * \      
    / . . ↙ . \     
   / . D 3 . E \    

       / . \        #Move 13
      / . . \       
     / . . . \      
    / . . . . \     
   / . * → D E \    

       / . \        #Move 14
      / . . \       
     / . . . \      
    / . . . . \     
   / . . E ← * \
```

The `*` represents the most recent peg removed. That is why the board starts with a `*` at slot `0` instead of a `0`. `.` represents an empty slot. The slots stay in the same position but the pegs are numbered and move around so for the very last move `peg E moves from slot E over peg/slot D to slot C`

The direction of the move is the unicode characters `u2190` through `u2199`

This is code golf so lowest number of bytes wins. Good Luck!

**If something is unclear don't hesitate to ask. I will do my best to clarify.**

Comment: I don't understand your representation of the board. There is no "0" peg at the beginning, but after the first jump, a "0" peg appears. So I thought maybe you are just numbering the positions, but then somehow a 3 ended up on the bottom row, which means the pegs are moving around. Can you explain your output?

Comment: @Rainbolt You were confused for good reason. I had my output screwed up but I think I fixed it and if not hopefully enough to be understood. I also added some clarification near the end

Comment: You've explained the meaning of the `*` and `.`, but the non-ASCII symbols are not mentioned. Are they required in the output?

Comment: That's the direction of the move which is required. I have that at the top but I'll make it more clear

Comment: @Rainbolt The input should always be valid. There's no need to check for invalid moves. Regarding the identifying holes vs pegs if you only identify holes then you can represent the pegs being moved, only the holes being filled or not which makes the board harder to read. It's however you want to look at it honestly. I chose pegs and holes to describe which peg was moving and to where. Lastly, I will change it to be hex only since the board doesn't display neatly with the last row being decimal.

Comment: @SirParselot Whoops, I deleted my comment right before you replied because it was only really a suggestion and this is your first challenge. By the way, you can post challenge in [the Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/18487) once you gain a tiny amount of reputation (I think 50?), and then you can get feedback on challenges before you post them. Totally optional, but highly recommended if you want your challenge to be polished before you post it.

Comment: @Rainbolt I appreciate the suggestions. I like hearing feedback about my challenge.

Comment: What are the rules of the game? Are you missing words to the effect of "For each move in the list" somewhere in the description of what should be output, or is the example covering lots of different inputs? How can we "*post your output as well*" if the output depends on the input? (And if it's going to be the same as the example output, why on Earth should we force everyone who wants to read the answers to scroll past a massive chunk of text which doesn't add any value to the page?)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sorry, I just assumed people would know the rules of the game. Everyone knows them from where I'm from. I'll post them. I will also add more description about the moves in the list.

Comment: We don't have Cracker Barrel restaurants outside the US. I've added a link to a website with the rules (it seems the name of the game is in fact peg triangle solitaire) but I think you should describe them also.

Comment: @steveverrill thanks, I completely passed over that detail

Answer (score 10):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-pa`, 181 bytes

```ruby
$_=b||=+-s=(1..5).map{|i|"/ #{[*:A6310[-i]..?E][0,i]*' '} \\".center 13}*$/+$/
f,o,t=$F.map{|i|s=~/#{i}/}
b.tr!(a='→↙↘*↖↗←',?.)?(b[t],b[o]=b[f],a[(o-f)/7]):$><<b
b[f]=?*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncy5boNAGATg/n@KiY3EYVhYY45Y3iBfeYn1KmIjW6KIsWxSRIaU1FGKHK/Hg4SQItIUo9GnOT/rl743HoSuazHxLsLijEU2e8pP17qoRz7GV@nMl3HIA@kVirFsq2TgFsoxYTbY7UbscX@s9mfwsHEMf2L4dHBLtxLG/f/LRbz642vR@A1pVp1vrFyYXfvetd9d@@V07UfXfnbtm@lmzM4sLSvlalkqoeVBubm0Su9g@4my58bdYqHpbxaZ0/cBPD6EQnAEtESMkFLMwGmFBDOaDj2hDdZY0S0iTIkjREwBpogoHkxKEVKsB7/GhrYY7E95qoryeOm9U/4L)

The score would be 169 if counted by characters. It's unfortunate that the arrow characters are 3 bytes each, but using them directly is shorter than every method I tried for generating their codepoints (which are irregularly spaced).

### Explanation

The board, stored as a multiline string, is padded out to a rectangular grid with leading and trailing spaces on each line. Let \$f\$ and \$o\$ be the indices within this string of the slots being jumped from and over, respectively. Then the following table describes all jumps, independent of the specific slots involved:

| Direction | \$o-f\$ | \$\left\lfloor(o-f)/7\right\rfloor\$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `←` | \$\phantom{1}{-2}\$ | \$-1\$ |
| `→` | \$\phantom{-1}2\$ | \$\phantom{-{}}0\$ |
| `↖` | \$-15\$ | \$-3\$ |
| `↗` | \$-13\$ | \$-2\$ |
| `↘` | \$\phantom{-{}}15\$ | \$\phantom{-{}}2\$ |
| `↙` | \$\phantom{-{}}13\$ | \$\phantom{-{}}1\$ |

Conveniently, we see that \$\left\lfloor(o-f)/7\right\rfloor\$ yields a unique value between \$-3\$ and \$2\$ for each jump direction, ideal for indexing into a string (`a`) containing the arrow characters.

###### Flags

`-p`: Loop through the code for every line of input and implicitly print the contents of `$_` at the end of each iteration.

`-a`: Form the array `$F` by splitting the input on spaces.

###### Line by line

```ruby
$_=b||=+-s=(1..5).map{|i|"/ #{[*:A6310[-i]..?E][0,i]*' '} \\".center 13}*$/+$/
```

Two boards are saved: `s` is the starting configuration (all slots filled) whereas `b` (shadowed by `$_`) is the current configuration. For each line \$i\in[1,5]\$ in `s`, slot numbers are generated by taking the first \$i\$ elements of a character range beginning with `0`, `1`, `3`, `6`, or `A` and always ending with `E`. Each line is padded with leading and trailing spaces (`.center 13`), the lines are joined by newlines (`*$/`), and a trailing newline is appended (`+$/`).

On the first iteration only, `s` is cloned into `b` (`b||=+-s`). `$_` is set equal to `b` so that the board will be printed at the end of each iteration. Since `b` and `$_` point to the same string object, all subsequent operations on `b` affect `$_` too.

```ruby
f,o,t=$F.map{|i|s=~/#{i}/}
```

Map the input slot numbers to indices in `s`, saving the results in `f` (jump_from), `o` (jump_over), and `t` (jump_to). The mapping is as follows: `0 → 6, 1 → 19, 2 → 21, 3 → 32, 4 → 34, 5 → 36, 6 → 45, 7 → 47, 8 → 49, 9 → 51, A → 58, B → 60, C → 62, D → 64, E → 66`.

```ruby
b.tr!(a='→↙↘*↖↗←',?.)?(b[t],b[o]=b[f],a[(o-f)/7]):$><<b
```

In `b`, replace the `*` and arrow character from the previous jump with `.`. The shouty `.tr!` modifies `b` in place, returning `nil` (falsey) on the first move (no previous jump so no replacements performed) and `b` (truthy) on all other moves. If it is the first move, print the board with all slots filled (`$><<b`). Otherwise, update the jump_to slot with the peg from the jump_from slot and set the jump_over slot to the appropriate arrow character by indexing into `a` as described above.

```ruby
b[f]=?*
```

Set the jump_from slot to `*`, after which the board is implicitly printed.